# Objective C - Copying NSArray doesn't really copy the objects?

Tags: objective-c, copy, nsarray

Copying an array  would create a new instance of the array, but the objects in the array are still being referenced from the old array. Isn't this a bug?

Item in array:     **Item: 0xa623800**

Item in new array: **Item: 0xa623800**

```
po [self selectedItems]
(NSMutableArray *) $1 = 0x0a21f1a0 <__NSArrayM 0xa21f1a0>(
<Item: 0xa623800>
)

po [[self selectedItems] copy]
(id) $2 = 0x0b854fd0 <__NSArrayI 0xb854fd0>(
<Item: 0xa623800>
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It did copy the array, but not the items in the array. That is a deep copy. I think you may want [`-initWithArray:copyItems:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithArray%3acopyItems%3a).

Comment: Correct;  `copy` is a shallow copy.  Note that `initWithArray:copyItems:` is still shallow;  if your array is full of arrays, it won't deeply copy the items in those arrays.  Deep copying is actually really hard to do generically.